# What console game has been released with the highest number of optical discs?

Tags: gaming-history, physical-media

Nowadays, games being released in 1 or 2 discs is considered normal (for example, RDR2 for PS4/Xbox One in 2 50GB Blu-ray discs and GTA V for the Xbox 360 was 2 9.5GB DVDs), but I remember that around the PS1 era games were released in a big number of discs (Final Fantasy 8 & 9 for the PS1 was released on 4 CDs).

What console game has ever been released in the highest amount of discs in total? Only actual game discs count (aka no Soundtrack, Demos or Movies) unless is used by the game in some way.

Comment: I recall Riven being 5 discs but I doubt that's the highest

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this question before here on Arqade. @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yeah, Baldur's Gate II with its expansions had 6 discs, but I think it was a lot higher than that indeed.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention: I kept PC games out because they are usually dictated by "market adoption restrictions" (for example, GTA V for PS3, PS4 and Xbox One is a single 50GB Blu-ray, but on PC is on 7 8.5GB DVDs probably due to BD Drives not being common on PC).

Comment: It's not about consoles so I won't post this as an answer, but PC games on CD-ROM could easily turn into high multiples as well, even before the DVD era. I remember having trouble to install one of the Eidos Interactive games I borrowed from a friend about 20 years ago. The game never ran, in part due to lack of memory, but the game came in a nice box with at least 6 CDs. Final Fantasy IX had 4. I'm sure there are more extreme examples out there. It used to be perfectly normal having to switch CDs (or even diskettes) during installation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Largest number I found:

- [Phantasmagoria](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EdAC_tHWsAIUfmk?format=jpg&name=small) has 8 CDs
- [Black Dahlia](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/y54AAOSw%7EHBenl7h/s-l1600.jpg) has 8 CDs
- [Everquest II](https://forums.mmorpg.com/discussion/14220/everquest-2-to-be-on-10-cds) has 9 CDs + 1 bonus disc

But it appears only Phantasmagoria was released for a console, Sega Saturn.

Comment: I was going to say The Legend of Dragoon for PS1, but that only has 4 :D

Comment: @nightsurfer FF8 and FF9 for PS1 had 4 too!